# Physically correct render of material covered with another material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

What is the physically correct way to setup light shaders for such object as wood plate covered with varnish? Wood and varnish have their own indexes of refraction, however they are kind of a single material now, since you can not split them apart. What is the common practice for such kind of things in Blender?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can layer reflections by using multiple layered mix nodes. This way you can controll roughnes, ior and bumpmap of each reflection layer separately. For example this is a simple carpaint shader using this technique.
[image]
it's far from perfect - it's just for demonstration.

Comment: just to add a bit of information, for more reallistic results, you can consult IOR tables, available online, specific for the material you want/need, like this:
http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-513458.html

Comment: Can I use this approach with specularity maps?

Comment: Sure you can plug a RGBmix node between the fresnel and the mix shader (either in the first or the second reflection layer - for varnished wood i guess in the first one) and set it to multiply. Then you insert the specularity map in the second input of the rgbMix. You can use the factor of the rgbMix to controll the influence of the specularity map.